# How to create page break between elements inside list entry?

Tags: jasper-reports, page-break

My Jasper Report has Detail element that holds List element. Every list entry of which contains number of tables.

I need to add page break between those tables.

The problem is that it is not possible to add line break. I am able to drag it between tables but the report stops working after adding it. It turns out that break is not supported in such places.

Is there a way to workaround this? Currently I'm thinking of adding some fake element that would consume some space but will be invisible, however it is not as simple.

I know it could be achieved by introducing sub-reports, but this requires complete redesign of my report so it is not an option for me.

Comment: AFIK there is no clean way of doing this. You are asking to much from the `jr:list` component, it's time to redesign replace the `jr:list` with a subreport and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks @PetterFriberg. Unfortunately it will be a way too hard/almost impossible with the solution I have. I still hope for some workaround.

Comment: Not even including a subreport with pagebreak in the `jr:list` component will work correctly, my feeling is that `jr:list` is not built to renderer page break correctly, at this point the only hope is searching in source code and change it accordingly.